# Get a backtrace from an error in `mclapply`

Tags: r, backtrace, mclapply

A toy example:

```
> f = \(x) if (x == 4) stop("Oh no!") else x
> x = parallel::mclapply(1:10, f)                                                   
Warning in parallel::mclapply(1:10, f) :
  scheduled core 2 encountered error in user code, all values of the job will be aff
ected
```

I can see the message I put in `stop`, "Oh no!", but not the call stack:

```
> x[[2]]
[1] "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Oh no!\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in FUN(X[[i]], ...): Oh no!>
> traceback()
No traceback available
```

Is there any way to see the call stack from where the error arose? I'm on R 4.2.1.

Comment: for quick debugging ,you can just set 'mc.cores=1', then it will run as normal lapply and you should see the error stack..
not sure if this helps but that's how i do it usually :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to track down an error that I can only reproduce under parallel processing.

Comment: haha ok, then thats useless

Comment: doesn't return the call stack but you could go old school and add print statements to the code that output to a file to see where it errors e.g. `cl = makeCluster(1, outfile="parallel_log"); f = \(x) {if (x == 4) { print(x) ; stop("Oh no!")} else x} ; x = parallel::parLapply(cl, 1:10, f) ;stopCluster(cl)` (not aware that this can be done on mclapply)

Comment: or I think futures e.g. future_lapply has better error logging

Comment: The `bettermc` package would have been very useful to you. Unfortunately, it has been archived by CRAN. You could try if the github version runs without issues: https://github.com/gfkse/bettermc